# .net core Migration error: Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

Im trying to set up a dotnet backend with separate projects, i have the API project(which is a webapi) as the main project, then i have the persistance project that contains the DataContext class.

DataContext.cs:

```
using Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Persistence
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And i am injecting the DataContext into the configuration services in The startup file:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

then when i try adding a migration using this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -s API -p Persistence
```

It gives me that error.

Please any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Is there any more information with the error than "I can't make the object"?

Comment: @gunr2171 this is the full error: Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Comment: From the link you posted: "The DbContext itself and any dependencies in its constructor need to be registered as services in the application's service provider. This can be easily achieved by having a constructor on the DbContext that takes an instance of DbContextOptions<TContext> as an argument and using the AddDbContext<TContext> method." Try doing that - make the parameter in your constructor `DbContextOptions<DataContext> options`.

Comment: @gunr2171 i did just that :  `public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
         : base(options)
        {
        }                          ` unfortunately it still gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

first of all check your connection string in appsettings.json and after that
run this commands for migrations

```
dotnet ef migrations add 1
```

then

```
dotnet ef migrations update
```

and if didnt work check you ef core package from *.csproject

Answer (score 0):

try to add an empty constructor:

public DataContext(){}

Comment: i did that now its giving me a different error:  `No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.`

Comment: try to override the OnConfiguring method on your Context like this one:            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {

                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("your connection string goes here");
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

put your (var app = builder.Build();) in Program.cs after than Adding your Context